# Is there any way to acces the database from a module file in NestJS?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, nodemailer

I am developing a send email feature with nestJS, i am using [Nest Mailer](https://nest-modules.github.io/mailer/docs/mailer);
Is there any way to get the "host", "port", "user" and "pass" from fields stored in a database table ? By the way, i am using TypeORM.
In the .module file, i'm configuring the plugin like this:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MailsController } from './controllers/mails.controller';
import { HandlebarsAdapter } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer/dist/adapters/handlebars.adapter';
import { MailsService } from './services/mails.service';
import { MailerModule } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer';

@Module({
  controllers: [MailsController],
  providers: [MailsService],
  imports: [
    MailerModule.forRoot({
      transport: {
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 587,
        ignoreTLS: true,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
          user: "",
          pass: "",
        },
      },
      defaults: {
        to: 'alain@dsi.fr',
        from: '"nest-modules" <modules@nestjs.com>',
      },
      template: {
        dir: __dirname + '/templates',
        adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(),
        options: {
          strict: true,
        },
      },
    }),],
  exports: [MailsService],
})
export class MailsModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as `MailerModule` has a `forRootAsync` method where you can define `imports`, `inject`, and `useFactory`, then yes, you could make a call to the database, assuming you have the entity set up for this. Possibly something like

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    MailerModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([MailerConfigEntity])],
      inject: [getRepositoryToken(MailerConfigEntity)],
      useFactory: async (mailerRepo: Repository<MailerConfigEntity>) => {
        const config = await mailerRepo.find();
        return { configObjectUsingConfig };
      }),
    }),
  ],
})
```

Comment: is there any way to use a service i developer in this code ?

Comment: Absolutely. Think of the `inject` array as your constructor, so long as you pass injections tokens (usually classes, but sometimes strings) to it, you can inject them into the `useFactory` method and use those injected properties in their

Comment: @JayMcDoniel it is not working, as I also want to achieve the same thing but getting issues with useFactory. Could you please guide me to the solution?

Comment: @KunalGhosh "it is not working" doesn't tell anyone else anything other than you've got some sort of problem. Specificity is great. I have no clue what your code looks like or what you're trying to do. It might be good to open a new post with the details of what's happening

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Could you please try to look into this issue I have posted just a few mins away? It will be really helpful if you provide some working solution....thanks!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70096364/is-there-any-way-to-access-the-database-related-stuff-from-a-module-file-in-nest

Comment: Not working getting error ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.

Comment: @RiteshKhatri that would have to do with how you set up your TypeORM connection. You probably use named connections, and as such you need to pass the name to the `forFeature()` and the `getRepositoryToken()`

Comment: Yes I have passed the entity in both the things

Comment: Like I said, you probably need the connection name, but the comments are not the place for extended support, so if you're still having trouble, please open a new question