# Is there any way to access the database related stuff from a module file in NestJS framework?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs

I am trying to fetch SMTP details from the database instead of picking them from .env files.
Can anyone suggest to me how to achieve it? You can find my app module file below -

**app.module.ts**

```
    @Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot(configService.getTypeOrmConfig()),
        LanguageModule,
        UsersModule,
        MailsModule,
        MailerModule.forRoot({
            transport: {
                host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
                port: process.env.SMTP_PORT,
                ignoreTLS: false,
                secure: false,
                auth: {
                    user: process.env.AUTH_USER,
                    pass: process.env.AUTH_PASS,
                },
            },
            defaults: {
                from: 'info@hacep.com',
            },
            template: {
                dir: process.cwd() + '/email-templates',
                adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(),
                options: {
                    strict: true,
                },
            },
        }),
        MiniCandidacyModule,
        ProgramsModule,
        AttachmentsModule,
        AdminConfigurationModule,
    ],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Let me mention one more thing that I have already tried with nestjs dynamic modules concept but was unable to fulfill my requirement. Am facing an issue with my mailer module. please find the app modules files changes & errors below-

**app.module.ts**

```
@Module({
imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(configService.getTypeOrmConfig()),
    LanguageModule,
    UsersModule,
    MailsModule,
    MailerModule.forRootAsync({
        imports: [AdminConfigurationModule],
        inject: [AdminConfigurationService],
        useFactory: async (adminConfigurationService: AdminConfigurationService) => {
            const options = await adminConfigurationService.getSmtpDetails()
            return options
        },
    }),
    MiniCandidacyModule,
    ProgramsModule,
    AttachmentsModule,
    AdminConfigurationModule,
   ],
   controllers: [AppController],
   providers: [AppService],
  })
  export class AppModule {}
```

**Error**

```
[Nest] 5520  -ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MAILER_OPTIONS (?). Please make sure that the argument AdminConfigurationService at index [0] is available in the MailerCoreModule context.   

Potential solutions:
- If AdminConfigurationService is a provider, is it part of the current MailerCoreModule?
- If AdminConfigurationService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within MailerCoreModule?       
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing AdminConfigurationService */ ]
  })

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MAILER_OPTIONS (?). Please make sure that the argument AdminConfigurationService at index [0] is available in the MailerCoreModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If AdminConfigurationService is a provider, is it part of the current MailerCoreModule?
- If AdminConfigurationService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within MailerCoreModule?       
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing AdminConfigurationService */ ]
  })

    at Injector.lookupComponentInParentModules (E:\projects\hacep\backend\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:193:19)
    at async Injector.resolveComponentInstance (E:\projects\hacep\backend\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:149:33)
    at async resolveParam (E:\projects\hacep\backend\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:103:38)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Injector.resolveConstructorParams (E:\projects\hacep\backend\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:118:27)
    at async Injector.loadInstance (E:\projects\hacep\backend\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:47:9)
    at async Injector.loadProvider (E:\projects\hacep\backend\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:69:9)
    at async Promise.all (index 3)
    at async InstanceLoader.createInstancesOfProviders (E:\projects\hacep\backend\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\instance-loader.js:44:9)
    at async E:\projects\hacep\backend\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\instance-loader.js:29:13
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your AdminConfigurationModule export the AdminConfigurationService?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Yes, I have exported the service file in the module. You can check the below code for **AdminConfigurationModule.ts** -

@Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Configurations, UserAccounts])],
    controllers: [AdminConfigurationController],
    providers: [AdminConfigurationService, UtilityService, LoggerService],
})

Comment: Next time, please add your code snippet as an edit to your question. The comments don't render them well. Anyways, your `MailerModule` never imports the `AdminConfigurationModule` and your `AdminConfigurationModule` never exports the `AdminConfigurationService` so this is all throwing errors like I'd expect it to

Comment: Ok, thanks for your suggestion of adding code in snippets. Now can you provide any reference or solution to make things dynamic in the app.module.ts file? Because we can't import anything in our in-built MailerModule. @JayMcDoniel

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your module is not global, you need to import it in your **app module:**

```
imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true })],
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your module is not global, you need to import it in your app module:

```
imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true })],
```

And then you need export it:

```
@Module({
 controllers: [ItemsController],
 providers: [ItemsService],
 exports: [ItemsService],
})
```